# Getting hyperlinks to roll over vertically in a #3D transform manner in a rectangular box

Tags: wordpress, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to get **hyperlinks to roll over** (like if you were in bed, rolling over from one side to another) **in a rectangular box**.  I have the following on a WordPress domain:

```
.entry-content a {
background: #28A2EE;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.entry-content a:hover {
background: #3a599d;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
transform: rotateX(180deg) scale(1.05) translateY(-22px);
    transition: background 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgCJs/) that AlienArrays created to reproduce what I'm seeing.  Also, you can see the [Privacy Policy page](http://www.jasonpaulweber.com/privacy-policy/) as to what the CSS above puts out.  But again, **I'd like the links to be rectangular boxes that flip, or roll over, vertically, when hovered.**

I thought this would flip the hyperlink, but I know I have to somehow put some type of transform: 3D type of CSS in there.  I just don't know how.

I'm a Code Canyon junkie, so Example 2 is from there, but his add-on doesn't work in IE (any version).

[Example 1](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/) (This is the EXACT example of what I'm trying to do!  The second layer of links shown in this example!)

[Example 2](http://codecanyon.net/item/roll-link-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/5262045) (From Code Canyon; Doesn't work in IE)

[Example 3](http://www.deutsche-stadtnachrichten.de/aus-allen-regionen/nordrhein-westfalen/stadt-frechen/2013/08/03/schuetzenfest-bachem/) (German site has it on his links; doesn't work in IE)

It's a WordPress site, so I don't want to get too complex with it.  Is it possible to adjust the above to achieve the rollover effect I'm looking for?  **Any guidance would be truly appreciated**!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/TgCJs/2/

This is what I added.

```
.entry-content:hover  {
    animation: myAnimateName 10s;
    display: inline-block;   // didn't work till added this
}

@keyframes myAnimateName {
    0% { transform: none; }
    100% { transform: rotatex(180deg); }
}
```

Here's an OK resource for more information http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

EDIT: also just adding display: inline-block seems to make the original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TgCJs work sort of how you want. Although there is a few kinks that need to be worked out. Possibly adding `<li></li>` tags around each `<a></a>` tag and using a pseudo `li:hover a` css selector would help.

Comment: Thanks Alien ... still looking into things.  I know that if I just sit here and play around with it for an hour, something will end up working!  I appreciate you taking the time for the fiddles!